# How to make multiple sets of boxplots with colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, seaborn

I've been trying to make a plot that is divided into 3 sections and each of those sections has 2 subsections that should each contain different colors in python like the picture below and I can't get it to work.[image]

I'm using this set of sample data:

```
year_2050_model1 = [50.2, 45,55]
year_2050_shift_model1 = np.array(year_2050_model1)+ 1.5

year_2100_model1 = [45, 43, 46]
year_2100_shift_model1 = np.array(year_2100_model1) + 1.5


####################################################################

year_2050_model2 = [56.2, 49,53]
year_2050_shift_model2 = np.array(year_2050_model2)+ 1.5

year_2100_model2 = [43, 48, 41]
year_2100_shift_model2 = np.array(year_2100_model2) + 1.5

historical = [50, 49,55]
observed = [54, 46,58 ]
```

I can plot each model individually, however setting it up in the format like the picture doesn't work, does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it to work/packages to try?

Thank you

I've tried placing everything into a single data set and plotting that, but seaborn will overlap the data together, and matplotlib does not let me have the right sections next to each other, and will not let me remove the gap between the normal model and the shifted model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `positions` argumet for the `ax.boxplot` method in matplotlib:

```py
info = {
    0: (historical, "historical"),
    1: (observed, "observed"),
    4: (year_2050_model1, "2050: M1"),
    5: (year_2050_model1, "2050: M1 Shift"),
    7: (year_2050_model2, "2050: M2"),
    8: (year_2050_model2, "2050: M2 Shift"),
    11: (year_2100_model1, "2100: M1"),
    12: (year_2100_model1, "2100: M1 Shift"),
    14: (year_2100_model2, "2100: M2"),
    15: (year_2100_model2, "2100: M2 Shift"),

}


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))

for k, (data, label) in info.items():
    ax.boxplot(data, positions=[k])

ax.set_xticks([k for k in info.keys()])
ax.set_xticklabels([v[1] for v in info.values()], rotation=90)

for i in (2.5, 9.5):
    ax.vlines(i, 40, 60, linestyles="--")
```

The colors and positions can be adjusted as required by changing the `info` dictionary to include additional items in the tuple value and using those in the `ax.boxplot` call

[image]